# Number Theory: Find all functions that $f(n)! = f(n!)$ and $m-n | f(n)-f(m)$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

> Find all functions like $f$ which take positive integers as argument,
>   that $f(n)! = f(n!)$ and for each natural numbers $m,n$ $m-n |
> > f(n)-f(m)$

Any hints how can i find functions that satisfy given condition?

Comment: The condition that $f(n)!=f(n!)$ seems very strong.  The condition that $(m-n)\mid f(n)-f(m)$ is satisfied by polynomials, but, it seems that the only polynomials which satisfy the original restriction are constant and the identity.

Comment: Yeah. In addition to what Michael Burr said $f(n)=n!$ (or any iterate) satisfies the first condition, but fails the second (set $m>1, n=1$).

Answer (score 0):

Hint : We know that :
$$ (n+1)!-n! > f(n+1)! -f(n)!$$ 
Hence we can't have  $$f(n!)>n!$$ because in this case the above statement will be false, and then only only constant functions satisfies the properties and the identity